# jquery не верная передача значения в контейнер select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

При инициализании списка автоматически задаю необходимый мне елемент списка как выбранный но иногда выбирается неверный. Вот в чем соль...

Когда у меня в списке: **'апельсин'**, 'банан','яблоко','клубничка)' Все ок.
Я задаю:

```
$('.edit_selectCategory option:contains("' + "апельсин" +'")').prop('selected', true);
```

И все гуд получаю 'апельсин'.
Но как только в списке появляется несколько похожих слово то выбирается последнее. Тоесть если в списке еще появится **'апельсин оранженый'** то я получу **'апельсин оранженый'** а не **'апельсин'**.

```
<select class="edit_selectCategory" style="width: 100%"></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Селектор `:containts` ищет подстроку, а не "только это".
Если нужно точное совпадение и не иначе, то как-то так:

```js
$('.edit_selectCategory option:contains("Апельсин")')
  .filter((i, el) => el.innerHTML.toLowerCase().trim() === 'апельсин')
  .prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='edit_selectCategory'>
  <option>Банан</option>
  <option>Апельсин</option>
  <option>Яблоко</option>
  <option>Апельсин Лиловый</option>
  <option>Клубничка</option>
</select>
```

Сначала ищем всё с этой строкой, затем используется функция [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), в которой выбираются уже точные совпадения.

**Note:**
Селектор `:contains` выбирает регистрозависимо, т. е. слова `Апельсин` и `апельсин` будут разными.

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.

Comment: Данная конструкция не работает в IE..."message": "Syntax error"  => ...Да и редпктор ругается на данный код(

Comment: Стрелочные функции - довольно новое явление (хотя уже пару лет есть), поэтому старые IE не работают, конечно. Можете переписать на обычную функцию.

Comment: IE11! В ногу со временем так сказать)

Comment: IE все отличаются удивительным желанием вставить палки в колесо прогресса.